# Cancelling display flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following structure

```
<div id="1">
    <img src="targetImage">
    <div id="2">
        google maps component in here
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue is that i'd like to use flexbox to center the `img` element. This is easily achieved by combining `align-items` and `justify-content` and works perfectly.

The issue is that the moment i add `display:flex` on the div with `id="1"` google maps disappears.

Of course **this makes sense as google maps is based on a different display attribute**, probably `block`. I was wondering how i can fallback to `display:initial` on the div with `id="2"`. Simply setting it to it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: i tried that but it doesnt work thus i was asking how i can cancel kids being flex items manually

Comment: have you tried giving `id=2` `width: 100%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this for your `2` div

```
width: 100%;
```

When you set the parent as flex, the map container loses its width because google map content is positioned absolutely. I tested this out on one of the sites I worked on and the map disappears when you set the parent as flex. If you use inspector, you can see the flex item has no width

Comment: This works. Quite the case here. Thanks a bunch, most importantly for explaining why.